# React native showing 3 card view in a screen and on scrolling showing next 3 card

Tags: react-native

[card view like that but when I horizontally scroll next set of 3 cards should be shown]

Displaying list of data in card view such that 3 cards are shown in screen at a time and when horizontally scroll we move to next 3 cards of data. I have used FLatlist and it makes my content vertically scrollable if I make it horizontally scrollable then only one card is shown.

Comment: FlatList is not what you looking for, try this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid or this https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager. Your must render 3 cards in each viewpager tab.

Comment: How can I make it work if I am getting data in json form how many cards I need at beginning